# Can't create Azure TemplateSpec due to invalid api-versions

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a TemplateSpec using Bicep and the New-AzTemplateSpec command in Az-PS. However, I'm encountering an error and need some help to resolve it:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidSchema",
    "message": "The template is invalid. Error: 'The template resource 'subscriptionDeployment' at line '168' and column '18' is invalid. The api-version '2018-11-01' used to deploy the template does not support 'Scope' property. Please use api-version '2019-05-01' or later to deploy the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-resources for usage details.'"
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding snippet from the ARM Template gets compiled after execution:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "name": "subscriptionDeployment",
      "scope": "/",
      "location": "[deployment().location]",
```

Created from this Bicep snippet:

```
resource subscriptionRes 'Microsoft.Subscription/aliases@2021-10-01' = {
  name: subscriptionName
  scope: tenant()
  properties: {
    displayName: subscriptionName
    billingScope: '/billingAccounts/${billingAccountName}/billingProfiles/${billingProfileName}/invoiceSections/${invoiceSectionName}'
    additionalProperties: {
      managementGroupId: managementGroupId
    }
  }
}
```

This is what my PS command looks like:

```
New-AzTemplateSpec -Name name -Version "0.0.1" -ResourceGroupName rgname -Location westeurope -TemplateFile "<path_to_bicep_file>"
```

I found similar posts, mentioning that the Cmdlets need to be updated and this is the part where I am not exactly sure. My Az.Resources PowerShell module which I thought is responsible for creating the TemplateSpec is on the newest version:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Resources

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
6.9.0                Az.Resources                        PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Azure Resource Manager and Active Directory cmdlets in Windows PowerShell and …
```

Also, I am using the newest PowerShell 7 version:

```
$PSVersionTable. PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      3      6
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

**Edit:**
The output I get from listing the api versions of my installed Microsoft.Resources module are as follows:

```
(Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Resources).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq 'templateSpecs'

ResourceTypeName : templateSpecs
Locations        : {East Asia, Southeast Asia, Australia East, Australia Central…}
ApiVersions      : {2022-02-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-03-01-preview, 2019-06-01-preview}
```

**Edit 2:**
This is the way I import the deployment into the main bicep file:

```
// Subscription
module sub 'artifacts/subscription.bicep' = {
  scope: tenant()
  name: 'subscriptionDeployment'
  params: {
    managementGroupId: managementGroupId
    subscriptionName: subscriptionName
    billingAccountName: billingAccountName
    billingProfileName: billingProfileName
    invoiceSectionName: invoiceSectionName
    budgetName: '${subShortName}-budget'
    amount: amount
    category: category
    timeGrain: timeGrain
    startDate: startDate
    endDate: endDate
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I now was able to find out the problem. The scope I gave to the module was wrong:

```
module sub 'artifacts/subscription.bicep' = { 
scope: tenant()
```

I need to set the scope of the module to 'managementGroup' and also set the targetScope to 'managementGroup' in the subscription bicep file I import (I found that out in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription-enterprise-agreement?tabs=rest#use-arm-template-or-bicep)). The scope property in the resource definition itself still needs to be of tenant().

Thank you very much Jahnavi for helping me through the process.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the template's Api-version `'2018-11-01'` does not support the `'Scope'` property. To deploy the template, you must use Api-version `'2019-05-01'` or later.

I see that you are running Api-version `"apiVersion":"2022-09-01"`. Try to modify it as `"apiVersion":"2019-05-01"` and deploy it to check compatibility.

You mentioned that you are using the most recent version of the `Az.Resources` PowerShell module, yet it is possible that this version does not support the requisite Api-version.

*Note:*

1. Update the `Az.resources` module if required using below command.

   `Update-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force`
2. Try retrieving the providers with their Api-versions that are available and registered in your environment as shown.

```
Get-AzResourceProvider -Listavailable
(Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Resources).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq 'templateSpecs'
```

By referring to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/quickstart-create-template-specs?tabs=azure-powershell) template spec deployment template for storage, I tried the similar deployment in my environment by changing the -version parameter to `-Version "2.0"` and it worked as expected.

```
New-AzTemplateSpec -Name xxxx -Version "2.0" -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> -Location westus2 -TemplateFile "stoa.bicep"
```

[image]

*If still the issue persists, clear the cache and redeploy the template spec deployment.*

**Update:**

```
targetScope = 'tenant'
var SubscriptionName = 'Free Trial'
resource Subscription  'Microsoft.Subscription/aliases@2020-09-01' = {
scope: tenant()
name:guid(SubscriptionName,  tenant().tenantId)
properties: {
displayName: SubscriptionName
billingScope: '/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxxxx'
workload: 'Production'
   }
}
```

I tried the above bicep code for subscription alias with api-version `2020-09-01` and the deployment was successful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. I've tried manually modifying the apiVersion of the respective resource in the ARM template, sadly no luck. I put the output I get when I retrieve the provider in the question, can you review it? Changing the version made no difference for me. To reproduce, could you try to create a TemplateSpec from a Bicep Subscription Alias?

Comment: I will work on it and update you. @CUiD8pdQJh

Comment: I updated the answer as per your requirement. Please check. @CUiD8pdQJh

Comment: Now this gets very interesting - I also can compile the singular bicep file including the subscription deployment into an ARM template and then use New-AzTemplateSpec to build and publish a TemplateSpec. However, the bicep file is part of another bicep file and gets included as a module. (I will update my question to include the module import to the main file) I can build the ARM Template of the main bicep file, but can't create a TemplateSpec out of it due to the error. So the issue could be related due to the deployment being imported. I am confused